# Fancybox v2 navigation/close buttons not showing on iPad or i?Phone

Tags: iphone, ipad, fancybox-2

The left/right and close buttons work fine on any device except the iPhone and iPad. They will not display at all.

The following is in my header of the page as per the instructions on http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/:

```
<link href="css/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link href="css/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.